# High-quality webcam for streaming

Tags: video, webcam

For years now, the only webcam I've (rarely) used is the [Logitech C200](http://support.logitech.com/product/webcam-c200). This is by far outdated now and I'm looking for a high-quality, powerful webcam that would be ideal for streaming. I've looked through the well-known Logitech webcams, and there are some good ones but not quite what I need. These specs are required:

- 1080p resolution
- H.264 video compression
- manual and/or auto focusing
- > 30fps (something around 45 or 60 fps is ideal)
- USB connection
- 5 or more megapixels (optional, since this is almost nonexistent)

Optionally, an independent stand and built-in stereo mics would come in handy every now and then.

Budget: $100 USD

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for ≥30 fps (i.e., 30fps is OK) or do you actually mean > 30 fps (i.e., 31 fps is OK, but 30 is not.)

Comment: @derobert Greater than 30 fps. However, it is implied that _greater than_ essentially means _much greater than_, so something like 60 or 45 fps is ideal and 31 is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best webcam I have used are the various models of Microsoft lifecam. With the lifecam, I have had good success with:

- HD quality
- Great color balance (the best I have had with any cam)
- Very good low light operation and color balance -- best I have experienced.

The Lifecam Studio, which is a notch above the lifecam model I have used, looks to meet all your specs:

https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/webcams/lifecam-studio/q2f-00013

Comment: Is the model linked the one you've had experience with?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Logitech C920](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920?crid=34). It fits perfectly in your budget at $99.99. Here's the features it offers:

- 1080p Full HD Recording
- Dual Microphone
- H.264 compression
- Tripod mount
- Low light correction
- Autofocus
- Connection through USB

Comment: I have stated that I've already considered Logitech's webcams.

Comment: @Adam But why does this webcam not meet your requirements?